# How do I get FTP's current working directory using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get current working directory of FTP using python?

I have the following code and wanted to store file names into the list in the root directory.

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('domainname.com')
ftp.login(user='username',passwd = 'password')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ftp.pwd` to get current working dir.

**Ex:**

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('domainname.com')
ftp.login(user='username',passwd = 'password')
ftp.pwd()                      #Current working dir
ftp.cwd("Destination_Path")    #To change to a different path
```

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.pwd)**